# Laravel calculate and ignore the null value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to perform a calculation on my controller I have this problem how do I ignore if one of the columns is NULL, like the way excel handles on an empty cell.

```
$data = $request->input('datas'); //here scores is the input array param 
foreach($data as $row){ 
    $grade = Grade::find($row['id']); 
    $grade->final_average =round( ($row['term1_result'] + $row['term2_result'] + $row['term3_result'] + $row['term4_result'])/4);
```

if one of the RESULT is empty it will ignore and calculate only the remaining result the same as excel.

**Found Solution**

Hello Guys I found the answer for this problem sorry for trouble-ling you guys i will post the answer here below for reference if someone has issue i use this small little code at the end. **?: null** 
so this is the final code

```
$data = $request->input('datas'); //here scores is the input array param 
foreach($data as $row){ 
    $grade = Grade::find($row['id']); 
    $grade->final_average =round( ($row['term1_result'] + $row['term2_result'] + $row['term3_result'] + $row['term4_result'])?: null/4);
```

Thank you for your help guys!..Appreciate it.

Comment: what is `$row`? from a model or what?

Comment: i have updated the code

Comment: so it's from the form input?  You should use the array in the result input. example `input name="datas[term_result][]">` will give like below  `$row["term_result"][0]`, `$row["term_result"][1]`,  etc

Comment: can you give me example below using my code.

Comment: so if there is one null value in your result out of 4 average must be calculated by division of 4 instead of 3. Correct ?

Comment: it should be divided by 3 not 4,

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best way to handle this would to have used `COALESCE` in your SQL query, e.g.

```
SELECT
    ...,
    COALESCE(term1_result, 0) As term1_result,
    COALESCE(term2_result, 0) As term2_result,
    COALESCE(term3_result, 0) As term3_result,
    COALESCE(term4_result, 0) As term4_result
FROM yourTable
...
```

Then, a `NULL` value would just be replaced by a zero.

Comment: i don't want to replace with zero, cos it will affect the average it will not completely ignore it will calculate . i want the way excel do .

Comment: Please post your SQL query along with some sample data.  I can't guess at what you want here, but handling this problem in the SQL layer may the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
foreach($data as $row){
    $keys = ['term1_result', 'term2_result', 'term3_result', 'term4_result'];
    $sum = 0;
    $count = 0;
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if ($row[$key] !== NULL) {
           $count += 1;
           $sum += $row[$key];
        }
    }
    $final_average = $count > 0 ? round($sum / $count) : 0; 
}
```

Comment: @Greigh the final_average is not what you want ?

Comment: that's the error i get when i use ur code; final average must be divided by 3 if 1 of the TERM is null ..